# Google Pay- com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException: 6: BuyFlow UI needs to be shown

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments, google-pay

I'm trying to implement a payment request for google pay natively on Android for a custom merchant(Stripe) and I'm receiving this error:com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException: 6: BuyFlow UI needs to be shown.
I'm attaching the JSON request(Note: I'm working on TEST Environment)

```
{
"apiVersion": 2,
"apiVersionMinor": 0,
"allowedPaymentMethods": [{
    "type": "CARD",
    "parameters": {
        "allowedAuthMethods": ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"],
        "allowedCardNetworks": ["AMEX", "DISCOVER", "JCB", "MASTERCARD", "VISA"]
    },
    "tokenizationSpecification": {
        "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
        "parameters": {
            "gateway": "stripe",
            "stripe:version": "2018-10-31",
            "stripe:publishableKey": "YOUR_PUBLIC_STRIPE_KEY"
        }
    }
}],
"transactionInfo": {
    "totalPrice": "10.00",
    "totalPriceStatus": "FINAL",
    "currencyCode": "USD"
}
}
```